# try catch duo in c++

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I know that the general method for using the try catch duo is something like this:

```
try
{
   //your code
}
catch(...)
{
   //any error goes here
}
```

Is there a way by which catch() catches the error code without giving any input... i.e if I didn't throw an exception but the c compiler did, then the error code can be anything. I just need to catch whatever the error code is and be notified that's all.

Comment: What do you mean by "but the c compiler did"?  What are you expecting to be thrown?  Are you trying to translate error code returns into exceptions?  Are you trying to catch non-C++ exceptions (e.g. structured exceptions on Windows)?

Comment: You mean exception thrown by standard library of C++?

Comment: yes i meant errorcode returns into exceptions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, you're trying to `catch` errors from functions that don't throw exceptions but return numerical error codes. That's impossible. The closest you can get is wrapping all your C functions in exception throwing code yourself:

```
FILE *safe_fopen(char const *path, char const *mode)
{
    FILE *f = std::fopen(path, mode);
    if (f == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
    return f;
}
```

It is not possible to throw an exception when a program derefences a null pointer or an invalid piece of memory, at least not in a portable manner; when that happens, behavior is simply undefined. There's no error code to check for, just a segfault on most OSs.

But please get your terminology straight. The **compiler** does not throw an exception, a **function** may do so, at run-time. The **C** compiler has very little to do with all this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to catch everything. If you only want to handle a particular type of exception, only catch that exception:

```
try {

} catch (MyExceptionType ex) {

}
```

Comment: what if i would like to catch any exception that the try statement gives such as if the try statement segfaultd coz f trying to access 0x000000 and things like that...

Comment: If you would like to catch *any* exception, then the code you posted works correctly. Use `catch(...)`.

Comment: @Prasanth:  There is no portable way to handle that sort of error (and really, if your program does that, you likely have other errors that can't be handled cleanly, so you should just fix your errors).  Are you targeting a specific C++ implementation / OS / runtime?

Comment: @Pra Figure out what kind of exception it throws, if any. If what you're trying doesn't raise exceptions, you cannot use exception handling to recover.